# Select box validation is having problem after adding a required attribute

Tags: html, validation, drop-down-menu, w3c-validation

I got a problem when I'm validating this. I can't understand how do I fix it?

```html
<Label for="religion">Select Your Religion</Label>
<select required class="form-control" id="religion">
    <option disabled>Select Your Religion</option>
    <option value="hindu">Hindu</option>
    <option value="muslim">Muslim</option>
    <option value="christian">Christian</option>
    <option value="buddhist">Buddhist</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Here is the problem I'm getting on https://validator.w3.org/nu :

> The first child option element of a select element with a required attribute, and without a multiple attribute, and without a size attribute whose value is greater than 1, must have either an empty value attribute, or must have no text content. Consider either adding a placeholder option label, or adding a size attribute with a value equal to the number of option elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `name` attribute is missing for your select option

Also, the select option should have `value=""`

```
<Label for="religion">Select Your Religion</Label>
<select required name="religion" class="form-control" id="religion">
   <option value="">Select Your Religion</option>
   <option value="hindu">Hindu</option>
   <option value="muslim">Muslim</option>
   <option value="christian">Christian</option>
   <option value="buddhist">Buddhist</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the validator message says

> ...must have either an empty value attribute, or must have no text content...

Make sure your option has an empty value, like `<option disabled value="">`

```html
<Label for="religion">Select Your Religion</Label>
<select required class="form-control" id="religion">
    <option disabled value="">Select Your Religion</option>
    <option value="hindu">Hindu</option>
    <option value="muslim">Muslim</option>
    <option value="christian">Christian</option>
    <option value="buddhist">Buddhist</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```